# What is the theory of evolution in Islam?

Tags: quran, hadith, islamic-philosophy, theology

What is the basic theory of evolution in Isalm? How can I describes the beginning of evolution after creation?

Comment: What evolution are you speaking about, when almost everybody says that religion and evolution are two opposite matters. Please clarify by editing your post!

Comment: I must say that I am a bit puzzled by the question when you say "How can I describes the beginning of evolution after creation?" Could you specify what you mean by "after creation", is this the pre-biotic world that you are referring to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Different scientist has theories of evolution and the most authentic theory is Dorwin theory in which it narrates the human are modified form of monkeys. This theory was later negated by the main scientists of time.
The most logical and understandable is theory of evolution of Islam in which Quran said that all human are derived from ADAM and Hawa. Quran also described all stages of birth like cycle of 40 days in which child get motion in mothers abdomen. Like wise it clearly explained all stages of birth cycle of nine months. This theory was later verified by Science

Comment: Most of your verified proofs are questioned on our site which makes me wonder which theory is closer to truth and what this answer is worth: See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50864/how-cling-clot-stays-in-womb-for-40-days-and-lump-for-flesh-for-anther-40-days-w https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41004/if-we-are-all-descendants-of-prophet-nuh-a-s-why-are-we-so-many-races?s=12|15.3293 etc. Beside if Darwin's theory was negated why would it still be taught all over the world with a few exceptions?